# How to select row value from given columns based on comparison of other column values in Pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
true_y  m1_labels   m1_probs_0  m1_probs_1  m2_labels   m2_probs_0  m2_probs_1
                        
0       0           0.628205    0.371795    1           0.491648    0.508352
0       0           0.564113    0.435887    1           0.474973    0.525027
0       1           0.463897    0.536103    0           0.660307    0.339693
0       1           0.454559    0.545441    0           0.512349    0.487651
0       0           0.608345    0.391655    1           0.499531    0.500469
0       0           0.816127    0.183873    1           0.456669    0.543331
0       1           0.442693    0.557307    0           0.573354    0.426646
1       0           0.653497    0.346503    1           0.487212    0.512788
0       1           0.392380    0.607620    0           0.627419    0.372581
0       1           0.375816    0.624184    0           0.631532    0.368468
```

This is a collection of disagreeing ML model predictions with labels and label probabilities of two models (`m1, m2`) and the actual label (`true_y`).

I would like to have any of the hard label predictions (`m1_labels` or `m2_labels`) which have a higher probability to the respective predicted class of their respective models per row. So for row #1, I expect `0` (as the `m1` model has a higher probability for its prediction `0` than the `m2` model for its prediction `1`). Basically, this is intended to be a manual voting ensemble of the two models.

How can I get this vector with a Pandas query?

Comment: which probability do you want to use? _0 or _1? What if they disagree?

Comment: I want to use the one that is the highest overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the apply function for this:

```
 df.apply(lambda x: x["m1_labels"] if max(x["m1_probs_0"], x["m1_probs_1"]) > max(x["m2_probs_0"], x["m2_probs_1"]) else x["m2_labels"], axis=1)
```

This select the first model label if the probabilty of its predicted class is higher than the probability of the second model predicted class. Otherwise, it selects the label from the second model.

Comment: Using `apply` in such a simple case if not needed (`apply` is inefficient)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# get max probability for m1
p1 = df.filter(like='m1_probs').max(axis=1)
# get max probability for m2
p2 = df.filter(like='m2_probs').max(axis=1)

# m1_label if it has a greater probability, else m2_label
df['best'] = df['m1_labels'].where(p1.gt(p2), df['m2_labels'])
```

output:

```
   true_y  m1_labels  m1_probs_0  m1_probs_1  m2_labels  m2_probs_0  m2_probs_1  best
0       0          0    0.628205    0.371795          1    0.491648    0.508352     0
1       0          0    0.564113    0.435887          1    0.474973    0.525027     0
2       0          1    0.463897    0.536103          0    0.660307    0.339693     0
3       0          1    0.454559    0.545441          0    0.512349    0.487651     1
4       0          0    0.608345    0.391655          1    0.499531    0.500469     0
5       0          0    0.816127    0.183873          1    0.456669    0.543331     0
6       0          1    0.442693    0.557307          0    0.573354    0.426646     0
7       1          0    0.653497    0.346503          1    0.487212    0.512788     0
8       0          1    0.392380    0.607620          0    0.627419    0.372581     0
9       0          1    0.375816    0.624184          0    0.631532    0.368468     0
```